# SQL Server 2008: HOW TO GET PREVIOUS STATUS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count people whose current status is 3 and whose previous status is not 2 for each month. The SQL is like below:

```
SELECT  
    MONTH,
    COUNT(PERSON_ID) AS COUNT
FROM 
    STATUS S
WHERE 
    STATUS = 3 AND 'PREVIOUS_STATUS' <> 2
GROUP BY 
    MONTH
```

My question is: can anyone tell me how to write the SQL part to get 'PREVIOUS_STATUS' for those people with current status =3? Thanks!

The structure for status table:

```
   Person_ID            Status       Month
  -------------------------------------------
    101                    1          07/15
    101                    2          09/15
    101                    3          12/15
    102                    1          02/15
    102                    3          05/15
    103                    1          03/16
    ...                   ...          ...
```

Comment: What type is the `MONTH` field?

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SCREAMING AT ME? I DIDN'T DO ANYTHING!!111ELEVEN!

Comment: no, seriously, no harm done, but it's a bit impolite to use Caps Lock for normal text.

Comment: @melpomene : string

Comment: Haha, good effing luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `month` is stored in a reasonable format, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select month, count(*)
from status s outer apply
     (select top 1 s2.*
      from status s2
      where s.person_id = s2.person_id and s2.month < s.month
      order by s2.month desc
     ) as sprev
where s.status = 3 and (sprev.status is null or sprev.status = 2)
group by month;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: The sql got me data for all months. How can I get data for specific timeframe, for example, '07/2015' to '06/2016'? Thanks!

Comment: @Ice . . . You would add a `where` clause to the outer query.